# combine SOQL queries with different order by

Tags: apex, soql

I have 2 SOQL queries based on the different 'order by'. Below are the queries

```
list<case> CaseTypeA = [Select Id, status, createddate , Priority from case where status = 'New' order by createddate]
```

There is another set of cases which need to be ordered based on Priority and createddate.

```
if(typeB){
   list<case> CaseTypeB = [Select Id, status, createddate , Priority from case where status = 'New'
   order by Priority,createddate]    
}
```

Is there a way, I can combine these 2 in a single SOQL query such that if typeB , then it orders based
on Priority and createddate, else it orders based on the createddate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) you could use [Database.query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_query) method.
Just create a String variable with the ordering you should use, then append it to the query string.

```
String ordering = typeB ? 'Priority, CreatedDate' : 'CreatedDate';
List<Case> sortedCases = Database.query('Select Id, Status, CreatedDate, Priority FROM Case WHERE status = \'New\' ORDER BY ' + ordering);
```

---

Keep in mind that dynamic SOQL can’t use bind variable **fields** in the query string, only simple bind variables is allowed.
**Invalid** (binding a variable field):

```
Account myAccount = ...
// the following line will throw an error
Database.query('Select Id, Status FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :myAccount.Id');
```

**Valid** (binding just a variable):

```
Account myAccount = ...
Id accountId = myAccount.Id;
// the following line will be ok
Database.query('Select Id, Status FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :accountId');
```

Comment: the `AccountId = :accountId` is still a variable bind, it's just a simple one. Dynamic SOQL doesn't handle anything that needs additional processing, as it were (like getting the Id from an SObject variable instead of from an Id variable)

Comment: @DerekF I think that's what RubenDG meant when they said "bind variable fields" - the fields can't be accessed.

Comment: @DerekF Viktor got it right, I just quoted the documentation, which makes a difference between "simple bind variables" (`AccountId = :accountId`) and "bind variable **fields**" (`AccountId = :myAccount.Id`). I edited the answer for more clarity